# Stationing: optimizacion de codigo en python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, optimización

estoy intentando hacer una tabla con registros de Start_Station, End_Station y 283 columnas mas que representan variables.
con un código simple he logrado que esto funcione correctamente, sin embargo cuando lo hago la prueba con un archivo de datos mas grande (41000 registros), se vuelve interminable, aproximadamente 16 hrs de proceso. Pienso que debe de haber otra forma de hacerlo, sin embargo, no tengo idea como.

Alguien que quiera colaborar en este codigo, se los agradeceré.

El origen de los datos es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que espero es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código utilizado es:

```
import numpy as np

#seleccionar archivo de excel
xls=pd.ExcelFile('8.-Ejercicio Demo Macro DynSeg.xlsx')
#seleccionar nombrede la hoja
DF=xls.parse('data_2')
datos=pd.DataFrame(DF)
ini=datos['Start_Station']
fin=datos['End_Station']
valor=['Value']
variables=datos['Variable']
dyseg_ini=sorted(set(ini))
dyseg_fin=sorted(set(fin))
dyseg_var=sorted(set(variables))

tabla=pd.DataFrame({'from':dyseg_ini,'to':dyseg_fin})

p=0
avance=0
for variable in dyseg_var:
    tabla.insert(p+2,variable,'',False)
    p=p+1
total=len(dyseg_var)
for each_filtro in dyseg_var:

    filtro=pd.DataFrame(datos.loc[datos['Variable']==each_filtro, ['Start_Station','End_Station','Variable', 'Value']])
    avance = avance + 1
    print('Procesando...'+ each_filtro,end='\r')

    for index, cada_filtro in filtro.iterrows():
        for i,row in tabla.iterrows():
            if tabla.at[i,'from']>=filtro.at[index,'Start_Station'] and tabla.at[i,'to']<=filtro.at[index,'End_Station']:
                tabla.at[i,each_filtro]=filtro.at[index,'Value']
                next
    print(str(avance) + '/' + str(total) +' DEBUG  : Terminado '+each_filtro)

print(tabla)
tabla.to_csv('prueba.csv' , header=True , index=False)
```

Anexo los archivos de input:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w149s1vcukok60i/Plantilla%20de%20datos.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Buenas Arturo, no te voy a dar la respuesta, pero espero que el camino que te doy te sirva para resolver tu problema. Como te pongo en la respuesta te sugiero aprender Dask mediante tutoriales, documentacion y artículos en internet. Hay bastante literatura al respecto y es sencillo. Y después ya si quieres complicarte más, seguir con Numba

Comment: Si usas `iterrows()`, te cargas toda la potencia de pandas. Intenta utilizar las funciones de pandas que actúan sobre dataframes completos (o columnas completas), sin iterar tú mismo por cada fila, pues de aquí es de donde vienen siempre los problemas de performance.

Comment: He intentado comprender el código que has puesto, pero no lo he conseguido. ¿Podrías explicar con palabras qué transformación pretendes obtener de los datos de entrada? Es posible que pueda hacerse mediante primitivas pandas, que serían mucho más eficientes que la iteración por filas y las comparaciones entre celdas.

Comment: El codigo lo que hace es buscar los nodos de secciones es tomar los valores de la columna "Variable" y lo agrega como una columna, despues busca en la tabla de datos y busca donde cae cada segmento.

Answer (score 1):

Para estos Dataframes tan grandes, o incluso para dataset pequeños pero que vayas a realizar procesos muy pesados (NLP por ejemplo), te recomiendo usar Dask. (aunque hay otras librerías como Numba).

**Te recomiendo** que aprendas a usar Dask, y una vez sepas usarlo pases a usar Numba o a mezclar las dos, ya que Dask, conociendo Pandas te va a ser sencillo, y Numba tiene muchas restricciones y casos, es bastante más complejo. Te quedo una explicación de ambas

## Dask

[Aquí puedes ver la documentación](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

**Dask** es muy similar a pandas, de hecho hay muchísimas funciones que se llaman, y funcionan exactamente igual. Está diseñado para que se fácil de aprender si sabes usar pandas.

#### Entonces ¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Hay varias, aquí te dejo las más importantes

- Pandas usa "single-threading" es decir, solo utiliza un hilo para realizar las operaciones. Mientras que Dask puede usar "multi-processing", es decir puede utilizar todos los hilos y potencia de tu procesador (paralelizar).
- Dask al contrario que Pandas, usa lo que se conoce como "Lazy valuation" es decir, Dask cuando paralelizas una operación, no la ejecuta hasta que tú se lo pidas expresamente, simplemente la queda almacenada, tienes que usar el atributo `.compute()`
- Al tener Lazy Valuation te permite manejar dataset que tengan, 40G, 80G, 150G, etc. Cosa que con pandas es imposible (salvo que tu ordenador tenga esas capacidades de memoria RAM)

Estás son las tres principales diferencias, pero existen muchas más, **Con esto deberías acelerar tú código como mínimo 4 veces más (todo varía en función del código y el procesador que tengas). Te dejo **un ejemplo** de código simplemente para que veas como funciona

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

#cuento el número de hilos que tiene mi procesador
cores = cpu_count()

#con npartitions le indico que divida mi datasets en el número de hilos
dask_train = dd.from_pandas(df_train, npartitions=cores)


#Creo una función que ejecuta varias funciones, y es muy pesada
def df_clean(df_train):
    df_train['procesed'] = df_train.review.map(parse_html).map(remove_nonwords).map(lower).map(remove_stopwords).map(own_tokenizer).map(own_lemmatizer)
    return df_train

#guardo la operación
dask_train_processed = dask_train.map_partitions(df_clean, meta=df_train)

#le pido que lo compute utilizando toda la potencia del procesador
preprocessed_train = dask_train_processed.compute(scheduler='processes')
```

## Numba

[Aquí puedes ver la documentación](https://numba.pydata.org/)

Esta librería funciona con decoradores, y es más complicada de usar. pero por si misma o combinada con Dask aumenta bastante la velocidad de proceso de tus operaciones.

Lo que realiza Numba es compilar tu código Python y optimizarlo hasta llegar a velocidades de lenguajes como C o Fortran.

Además permite usar también computación en paralelo y hasta **CUDA** por lo que tú código puede ser ejecutado directamente en GPU.

Todo el código que he probado usando Numba solamente o Numba + Dask han realizado un aumento de velocidad de código impresionante. Operaciones que tardan 5 minutos mediante simple Python, **pueden realizarse en micro segundos!!** (dependiendo del tipo de operación que sea, y el PC que tengas por supuesto)